# CURL command line tool - Delete File from FTP server

Tags: curl, command-line, ftp, delete-file

I'm actually trying to use `CURL` to make some operations on a ftp server in C++ with Visual Studio. I've no trouble to do some uploads or downloads with commande line tools.

But for deleting some file I have some errors.

Here is the command I type:

```
curl -v -u username:pwd ftp://host/FileTodelete.xml -Q '-DELE FileTodelete.xml'
```

This is the answer:

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1ca5260
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1ca5260) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to host port 21 (
*   Trying ......
* Connected to host (...) po
< 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.49 beta
< 220 Bienvenue sur le serveur FTP de HandTrainer
> USER username
< 331 Password required for username
> PASS pwd
< 230 Logged on
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
> '-DELE
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
* QUOT command failed with 500
* Closing connection 0
curl: (21) QUOT command failed with 500
* Rebuilt URL to: FileTodelete.xml'/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1ca5260
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 1 (0x1ca5260) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Could not resolve host: FileTodelete.xml'
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: FileTodelete.xml'
```

Moreover, the file is on the server so I don't understand.

Comment: Note that, if you just want to delete your file, probably the first bug is that the file should not be mentioned in the ftp:// URL. Otherwise, also with the correct deletion parameters, then you risk to delete the file but returning the exit error status code `78`, since after deletion it automatically tries to access the deleted file (running `SIZE FileTodelete.xml` and obtaining a `550 Can't check for file existence` and then - running `RETR FileTodelete` and obtaining `550 Can't open FileTodelete.xml: No such file or directory` - as far as I've seen using `--verbose`). What was your source?

Comment: I totally understand your comment and it seems right indeed. What do you mean by "source" ? I was on my Windows personal computer if I remember.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Problem solved! The dash before `DELE` should not be there:

```
curl -v -u username:pwd ftp://host/FileTodelete.xml -Q "DELE FileTodelete.xml"
```

Comment: What dash? IMHO @chaos's answer is just this

Comment: @Marki I don't think that this answer mentions the user chaos at all. It just says that the original question (that comes from another user as far as I see) says `-Q '-DELE FileTodelete.xml'` with the dash

Comment: I think the answer is partially bugged. The correct command should be:
`curl -v -u username:pwd ftp://host/ -Q "DELE FileTodelete.xml"`
So without repeating the file in the URL. Otherwise, `curl` deletes the file but returning the exit error status code `78`, since after deletion it automatically tries to access the deleted file (running `SIZE FileTodelete.xml` and obtaining a `550 Can't check for file existence` and then - running `RETR FileTodelete` and obtaining `550 Can't open FileTodelete.xml: No such file or directory` - as far as I've seen using `--verbose`)

Comment: If you write a proper answer I will check it as an answer. I'm not working with that anymore for more than 9 years so I'm not sure I will and could check it. Dunno what to do in that cases. At the time it worked for me.

Comment: I can modify my answer too or maybe you can edit it I don't know

Answer (score 9):

You place a command with `-Q`, but `-DELE file` is not a common ftp command. Try one of these instead:

```
curl -v -u username:pwd ftp://host/FileTodelete.xml -Q 'DELE FileTodelete.xml'
curl -v -u username:pwd ftp://host/FileTodelete.xml -Q 'DELETE FileTodelete.xml'
curl -v -u username:pwd ftp://host/FileTodelete.xml -Q 'rm FileTodelete.xml'
```

Comment: This doesn't work : /

I tried the three but i got the same error message than previously.

Comment: I found what didn't work : trouble of permission for this user !
I'll post which command you submitted worked tonight.

Comment: Even after giving permission to the user, i still have the same error :
        500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.

Comment: From the curl man page: To make commands take place after a successful transfer, prefix them with a dash '-'. To make commands get sent after libcurl has changed working directory, just before the transfer command(s), prefix the command with '+'.

Comment: I think the answer is partially bugged. The correct command should be:
`curl -v -u username:pwd ftp://host/ -Q 'DELE FileTodelete.xml'` (or `DELETE` or `rm` etc.)
So without repeating the file in the URL. Otherwise, `curl` deletes the file but returning the exit error status code `78`, since after deletion it automatically tries to access the deleted file (running `SIZE FileTodelete.xml` and obtaining a `550 Can't check for file existence` and then - running `RETR FileTodelete` and obtaining `550 Can't open FileTodelete.xml: No such file or directory` - as far as I've seen using `--verbose`)

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished this task by first logging into my FTP server then typing "?" at the command line to get a list of commands recognized by my FTP server. The command recognized by my server was "delete".

So, -Q"delete $fileToRemove" $serverURL

I was also able to get it to work by using -X"DELE $fileToRemove" $serverURL. However, I kept getting rc=19 (because I think the "-X" option mostly applies to HTTP|HTTPS?) from curl when I used this argument even though the file was successfully deleted.

Not sure if other FTP servers recognize different commands but this is what worked for me.

Comment: I think running cURL in verbose mode, and uderstanding the underlying FTP commands with the `?` is a good troubleshooting approach. Please just add more syntax highlight in this answer, so it's more cute. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting
Also, I like this answer since it's the only one who has a clean server URL, instead of the others that has an incorrect server URL that includes the file to be deleted, so this answer does not cause a `cURL` exit error status code `78` and this is good.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info, to delete a file from non-root directory:
stays on root and delete file with path on the -Q command only

```
curl ftp://192.168.140.XXXX:21 -Q 'DELE ISOS/foo.iso'
curl ftp://192.168.140.XXXX:21 -Q 'DELETE ISOS/foo.iso'
curl ftp://192.168.140.XXXX:21 -Q 'rm ISOS/foo.iso'
```