# How to delete directory on FTP server with curl? (linux, shell)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

How can I delete a directory, which contains several files and sub-directories, with curl using the cmd shell (bash, ubuntu)?
I only know the name of the folder I want to delete.

This is a new question. I don't want to delete a file, I want to delete a directory, where I don't know the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CURL command line tool - Delete File from FTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721515/curl-command-line-tool-delete-file-from-ftp-server)

Comment: curl ftp://<server>/ -X 'rmdir <dirName>' --user myname:mypassword

Comment: It is not duplicate and I cannot use `rmdir` on the server...