# How to download file using PHP cURL and NOT delete file from remote server

Tags: php, curl

Currently I am successfully downloading a file using a PHP cURL request. The issue is that the remote file seems to get deleted after each download. Is there a setting to tell cURL to not delete the file after the download? I'm not finding anything on this when researching online. I'm actually only finding questions asking how to delete the files after downloading which is obviously working for me already but not my desired result.

Here is basically the code I am running currently:

```
$url = 'ftp://ftp.example.com/file.txt';
$username = 'username'; 
$password = 'password';
$filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/file.csv';

$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Would anybody happen to be able to provide me with some suggestions as to how NOT to delete the remote files?

Thanks!

Comment: curl cannot delete file from your server

Comment: If that's the case then which part of this code is telling it to delete form the remote server?

Comment: no part of this code is telling it to delete it. curl can't delete a remote resource. if the file really is being deleted, there must be something running on the remote server that's doing it, e.g. if the file is a one-time file only meant to be downloaded once, but there's zero chance that curl is deleting it, curl just sends requests for files & handles the data sent back

Comment: Thanks Rob.. That's what I was thinking, but was baffled when I seen the file getting deleted.. I just figured it was something in my code that I was unaware of.

Comment: minor clarification, as you're using ftp - you could probably issue FTP DELETE commands over curl to perform remote FTP deletions. Clearly, you're not doing that here, so that's not the cause, but it's incorrect to say that curl 'can't delete a remote resource'. see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721515/curl-command-line-tool-delete-file-from-ftp-server

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks again Rob..

Comment: you linked to command line curl example, in php you would add `curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_QUOTE, array('DELE /' . $testfile));`

Answer (score 0):

Well I've contacted the remote source and sure enough they were archiving the files just to keep the directory clean.

Thanks to all!